# (Python)Dataframe copy with selected columns and index

Tags: dataframe

Whole dataframe can be copied to df2 as below.
How to copy only 'B' column and index in df to df2?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, 30],'B': [100, 200, 300]}, index=['2021-11-24', '2021-11-25', '2021-11-26'])
df2 = df.copy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply select and then copy as follows:

```
df2 = df[['B']].copy()
```

I am using a list as the selection in order to have a `DataFrame` instead of a `pd.Series`.